# C++, The system cannot execute the specified program

Tags: c++

so I am new to C++ and recently I have been playing around with structures. I have this code below. This does not give me an error when I compile it but when it runs, it says "The system cannot execute the specified program." I have no idea why. I tested this code on my friend's computer and it works for him and when I deleted a member variable inside the struct the code runs perfectly. Also, when I initialize the object right before the ; in the end of the struct, my code works. But only with this specific layout my code doesn't work. I am not really sure why this is wrong. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct bob {
  int num1;
  int num2;
  int num3;
};

int main() {    
   cout << "Sup" << endl;
   bob test; 
   test.num1 = 10;
   test.num2 = 20;
   test.num3 = 30;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the shown code. Something must be wrong with your computer, compiler, or operating system. That, unfortunately, is not something that anyone on stackoverflow.com will be able to do anything about.

Comment: it could be the antivirus

Comment: What OS was this compiled for and what OS are you trying to run it on?

Comment: It could very well be the AV. I have seen several instances were AV either sandboxed a user built c++ application or just deleted it after compilation.

Comment: After building (successfully as you state), can you see the executable program in the file system? Is it in the location where you try to execute it? Can you show a `dir` or `ls` output showing the executable file?

Answer (score 2):

I hope you have found a solution to this problem so far.Still I would like to share my experience. I had the same problem , when I was trying to execute my c program's executable file in windows 10 pc. Then I came up with the idea to **uninstall the antivirus** which were restraining the executable file to execute. eventually that was the solution of this problem.